# How to fix 'TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data[index]')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

In a react-native project, when navigating to a specific screen, I get this error. but it isn't specific about where its location is. My best guess is that it has something to do with the FlatList thats being rendered in the screen component. Heres a screenshot [image]

I execute a redux action inside `componentDidMount`, in this same screen, which ultimately populates the redux store that is used as FlatList's data prop. Here's the flatList:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.messages}
    style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingBottom: 35 }}
    ref={'list'}
    onContentSizeChange={() => this.refs.list.scrollToEnd()}
    keyExtractor={(item) => {
      return (
        item.toString() +
        new Date().getTime().toString() +
        Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())).toString()
      );
     }}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        if (item.content.type == 'msg') {
            if (this.props.role == 'a') {
              return (
                    <Components.ChatMessage
                        isSender={item.sender == this.props.uid ? true : false}
                        message={item.content.data}
                        read={item.read}
                        time={item.time}
                        onPress={() =>
                            this.props.readMsg({
                                id: this.props.uid,
                                role: this.props.role,
                                convoId: this.props.navigation.state.params.convoId },
                                item.docId,
                        this.props.navigation.state.params.uid
                            )}
                     />
                );
            } 

        }}
    />
```

the `componentDidMount()` looks like:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.props.getMessages(this.state.ownerConvoId).then((success) => {
    if (this.state.ownerConvoId == this.props.messages[0]['userConvos'][0]) {
      this.setState({ withConvoId: this.props.messages[0]['userConvos'][1] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ withConvoId: this.props.messages[0]['userConvos'][0] });
    }
  });
 }
```

Not sure whats going on at all or where to look. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot it seems this is the offending line:

```
onContentSizeChange={() => this.refs.list.scrollToEnd()}
```

I would first check when that function is being called. I suspect you will be surprised at when it's happening. e.g. perhaps it's firing before `ref` is defined. Perhaps it's firing before the list has any content.

Update:

Spun up a fresh app and pasted your flatlist code like so

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";

export default class BadFlatList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={null}
                style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingBottom: 35 }}
                ref={'list'}
                onContentSizeChange={() => this.refs.list.scrollToEnd()}
                keyExtractor={(item) => {
                  return (
                    item.toString() +
                    new Date().getTime().toString() +
                    Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())).toString()
                  );
                 }}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    if (item.content.type == 'msg') {
                        if (this.props.role == 'a') {
                            return (
                                <Components.ChatMessage
                                    isSender={item.sender == this.props.uid ? true : false}
                                    message={item.content.data}
                                    read={item.read}
                                    time={item.time}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                        this.props.readMsg({
                                            id: this.props.uid,
                                            role: this.props.role,
                                            convoId: this.props.navigation.state.params.convoId },
                                            item.docId,
                                            this.props.navigation.state.params.uid)} />
                            );
                        } 
                    }
                }} />
        );
    }
};
```

Notice I replaced your

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.messages}
```

with

```
<FlatList
    data={null}
```

That reproduces what you are seeing. So I'd say your initial component state is passing in null data to your FlatList and that causes the problem. Just Check for missing data before rendering the FlatList and `return null` until the data is there.